How to pass Array of string as environment variable to Container in azure web app(linux) container?
I've one web app in place in azure, which consist of .Net core Webapi container image. All things are working as expected, but now i'm stuck in to pass Array of string as environment variable to container.
My setting is
Appsettings__EmailRecipients: "devlopers@gmail.com, admin.user@gmail.com"

At back end side, it's mapped as Array of strings by using traditional IConfiguration approach.
All other appsettings worked as expected, but not the array of string environment variable.
So, can someone please help?what's correct way to pass the Array of string as environment variable from azure web app?
I've tried injecting environment variables as below way, but still not worked
Appsettings__EmailRecipients0: devlopers@gmail.com
Appsettings__EmailRecipients1: admin.user@gmail.com

I'm able to resolve it by passing environment variable as below
Appsettings__EmailRecipients__0: devlopers@gmail.com
Appsettings__EmailRecipients__1: admin.user@gmail.com

